# Scrolltrigger Animating Children using forEach()

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, gsap

so I am extremely new to the world of GSAP and have spent a few hours messing around and and browsing the forums, but I have run into a bit of a roadblock that may be an obvious fix, but I cannot seem to figured it out. Figured it was time I asked for some help.

So, on my page I have 3 sections. Something similar to this -

```
<div class"section-title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Body Information</p>
</div>
<div class"section-title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Body Information</p>
</div>
<div class"section-title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Body Information</p>
</div>
```

What I am able to do, is use a forEach loop, and animate each section. Which is great, each .section-title loads its H1 and paragraph in at the same time.

However, what I would like to do, is be able to control the speed/delay of the H1 and paragraph within the section title.

(an example of what I have working) - https://codepen.io/_kprkr/pen/qBmVrWg

However, I have tried messing with the code to select the H2 whilst still triggering at the .section-title, but when I do something such as (https://codepen.io/_kprkr/pen/poPdewL)

To grab and edit the H1, it works for the first one, exactly how I would like it to, but the 2nd and 3rd instances of it are already loaded in.

I have tried a variety of From, to, fromTo, etc and figured I am clearly not on the right path and wanted to see what the right way is, rather than bruteforcing it with 20 different triggers.

Thanks!

Comment: You're making one of [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/st-mistakes/#generic) (read also [this common mistakes article](https://greensock.com/mistakes)).

Comment: Hi @ZachSaucier thanks for the reply, I have actually stumbled upon that during my searches (it is what directed me to using the forEach loop in the first place and gave me the working example above. But, it doesn't quite answer how I would go about adding more complexity to the fact I am trying to animate more than the ".box" it shows, but instead multiple within the .box itself.